# dfs.replication provides the replication factor, what does file.replication provide

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

My understanding is that the dfs.replication provides the number of replications that HDFS maintains, In the core-default.xml, I see "file.replication" along with "s3.replication", "ftp.replication" and "s3native.replication", could you please provide any inputs on the significance of these variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop supports different FileSystem implementations and all these properties define the replication factor to use for its corresponding file system.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Replication Factor Property| FileSystem       | URI Scheme | Java Implementation            |
|                            |                  |            | (org.apache.hadoop)            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| dfs.replication            | HDFS             | hdfs       | hdfs.DistriburedFileSystem     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| file.replication           | Local            | file       | fs.LocalFileSystem             | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ftp.replication            | FTP              | ftp        | fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem           |      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s3.replication             | S3 (block based) | s3         | fs.s3.S3FileSystem             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| s3native.replication       | S3 (native)      | s3n        | fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If the FileSystem scheme defined in `fs.defaultFS` is `hdfs://` then the replication properties other than that of HDFS will be never used.